# Perform diagonalization on a submatrix of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Is there an easy way to perform diagonalization on a sub matrix of a real symmetric matrix?

e.g.

$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & b & c \\
b & a_2 & d \\
c & d & a_3\end{pmatrix}$

To find an orthogonal matrix U, such that:

$U^T A U=\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & 0 & y \\
0 & x_2 & z \\
y & z & x_3\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks!

Comment: Let $V$ be a $2\times2$ orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes the submatrix, and tack on a bottom row and 3rd column of 0  0  1 to get $U$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think it works in this way... Have you tried a simple example?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Looks like I made a silly mistake. Don't worry about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerry Myerson answered in a comment:

Let $V$ be a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix that diagonalizes the submatrix; then 
$$U=\begin{pmatrix} v_{11} & v_{12} & 0 \\ v_{21} & v_{22} & 0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
does the job.